# How can rxjava manage a mutable collection?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a view which shows a list of devices connected with my phone, as new devices added and some devices disconnected, how can I create a subject with which I receive the current device list on the first subscription and subsequently receive add & remove events of the list.

Currently my implementation is a getDeviceList() method and a subject emits list change events. An event contains a type and a device properties. Is there any better implementation that can remove the additional event class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the event wrapper if you have different Observables for different event types: one for add events and one for remove events.